# chrome extension jquery ajax response with additional javascript code

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I implement chrome extension and i used  jquery `$.ajax` to get data from the server side by json, but the response returned with additional javascript code and this made the `error` always fired instead of the `success` although the response returned the json i sent from the server side.

the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.domain.com/ajax/getTags',
    data:{'cookie':cookie_value},
    type:'get',
    dataType:'json',
    beforeSend:function(){                  
    },
    success:function(data){
    },
    error:function(xhr, status, error){
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

and the response is :

```
    {"status":"error","msg":"<span class='error_msg alert'>Please complete the missing fields.<\/span>"}
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var uid = '3887';
      var wid = '4102';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.popcash.net/pop.js"></script>
```

the first line is the actual data sent by the server and all the next lines is additional data i don't know from where it came.

I used PHP in the server side and this is the script that return the json data

```
$json['status'] = 'error';
$json['msg'] = "<span class='error_msg alert'>Please complete the missing fields.</span>";
echo json_encode($json);
```

What's wrong? and how can i solve it ?

Comment: The problem is on the server. Is the response content-type set to `application/json`? What sever-side technology are you using to return the json?

Comment: you can see `dataType:'json'`, and i use php in the server side.

Comment: Yes I can see `dataType:'json'` but this is just telling JQuery to expect a json response. What's coming back from your server is not pure JSON, so it's ending up in the error block.

Comment: Is the PHP page you are using on a live server? Are you able to post the url?

Comment: this is the absolute url `http://www.savelinks.me/ajax/addTag?tag_name=&cookie=4c40e7e20b33f578b119ed4c2f4853ade2423ce5`

Comment: if you enter the url in a new tab and hit enter, then view source, you can see the additional javascript returned with the response.

Comment: Did you identify why the javascript was getting returned in the response?

Answer (score 0):

The server side page you are calling is returning `Content-Type:text/html`. You can start by setting this to return `application/json` in the PHP script.

```
<?PHP
$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

The JS scripts in the body looks suspect (especially given that you don't recognise this script), have you observed this script on all page calls. It looks like some kind of ad content delivery. Does the server you are hosting on belong to you? If so have you swept if for adware/malware?